# How create references between elements in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

Is possible do reference to an existing element in xml file?
I searched on Google but have not found the answers I was hoping for.

I start immediately explaining my goal:

```
    <Car id="car1">
        <plate>AAA</plate>
        <mark>Peugeot</mark>
    </Car>

    <Truck id="truck1">
        <plate>BBB</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
    </Truck>

    <Trailer id="trailer1">
        <plate>CCC</plate>
        <mark>Menci</mark>
    </Trailer>

    <TrailerTruck>
        <Truck id="truck1"/>
        <Trailer id="trailer1">
    </TrailerTruck>
```

... in this way I don't duplicate nothing.

Can be possible do this kind of references? If so, **how**?

---

I show you my **XML Schema**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

    <xs:element name="Fleet" type="FleetType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="FleetType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Car" type="CarType"/>
            <xs:element name="Truck" type="TruckType"/>
            <xs:element name="Trailer" type="TrailerType"/>
            <xs:element name="TrailerTruck" type="TrailerTruckType"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="VehicleType" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="plate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="mark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>



    <!-- Definitions: Car, Truck, Trailer -->

    <xs:complexType name="CarType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TruckType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TrailerType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>



    <!-- Definition: TrailerTruck -->

    <xs:group name="DrivingPart">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Car" type="CarType"/>
            <xs:element name="Truck" type="TruckType"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:complexType name="TrailerTruckType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:group ref="DrivingPart"/>
            <xs:element name="Trailer" type="TrailerType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

In this XSD, I have a *Fleet* of *Vehicles*.
*VehiclesType* is abstract. Instead *Car*, *Truck*, etc are concrete.
Pay attention on *TrailerTruck*.

An example of **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fleet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NewXMLSchema.xsd"> 

    <Car>
        <plate>AAA</plate>
        <mark>Peugeot</mark>
        <model>206</model>
    </Car>

    <Truck>
        <plate>BBB</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
        <model>X1</model>
    </Truck>

    <Trailer>
        <plate>CCC</plate>
        <mark>Menci</mark>
        <model>m2</model>
    </Trailer>


    <TrailerTruck>
        <Truck> <!-- Here I'm OBBLIGATE to rewrite all :( --->
            <plate>BBB</plate>
            <mark>Scania</mark>
            <model></model>
        </Truck>
        <Trailer>
            <plate>CCC</plate>
            <mark>Menci</mark>
            <model>m2</model>
        </Trailer>
    </TrailerTruck>


</Fleet>
```

Comment: So inside your `<TrailerTruck>` element, you want to refer to the *BBB* `Truck` and to the *CCC* `<Trailer>`? Did you try something with `<xs:key>` or `<xs:keyref>`?

Comment: Yes, is what I want. No, I not have tried. I use the Eclipse, and with his XML (and XSD) editor does not permit these tags... or not?

Comment: So the first example you provided in your post is what you would like to obtain? Or do you want full markup like in the last example? the permitted tags are up to you -- you have to declare them accordingly.

Comment: okay, how? My first example is an example of my goal. After this, I have attached my current implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the ID / IDREF feature of the schema. However, you need a specific attribute that will reference the ID value.

Thus I suggest you modify your schema like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="VehicleType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="plate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="mark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="refid" type="xs:IDREF"></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

along with an XML instance such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fleet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <Car id="car1">
        <plate>AAA</plate>
        <mark>Peugeot</mark>
        <model>Model AAA</model>
    </Car>

    <Truck id="truck1">
        <plate>BBB</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
        <model>Model BBB</model>
    </Truck>

    <Trailer id="trailer1">
        <plate>CCC</plate>
        <mark>Menci</mark>
        <model>Model CCC</model>
    </Trailer>

    <TrailerTruck>
        <Truck refid="truck1"/>
        <Trailer refid="trailer1" />
    </TrailerTruck>
</Fleet>
```

**Comments:**

1. now the content of a Truck or Trailer can be empty. It will be up to you to know if you want to use a complete content or not (only a reference). This minimizes the modification of the schema.
2. it is possible to locally define a Truck / Trailer element if in TrailerTruck which will only allow empty content, if you are sure you only need references within a `<TrailerTruck>`.
3. however (IMHO) I think it is better to use specific tag for references, e.g. `<TruckRef>`, `<TrailerRef>`. Thus you need to define these tags and modify model content of `<TrailerTruck>`.

Comment: It *works*! I had already tried with `xs:ID` and `xs:IDREF`, but remained mandatory rewrite all internal tags of a vehicle ... but adding `<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" >` the problem disappeared.

Now: 1) in case of a single vehicle, I want to fill all internal elements. Instead, in case of complex vehicle (TrailerTruck) I just want references. So I will take note of your suggestion number 3. But for now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPointer](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpointer.asp) to refer to other parts of an XML.