# How to control references between elements in XML

Tags: xml, reference, xsd

In my previous question ([How create references between elements in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365082/how-create-references-between-elements-in-xml))  I asked how to create, in an XML Schema, references between elements.

Ok, but now I noticed something. For example, defining these three types of vehicles:

```
<Car id="car1">
    <plate>AAA</plate>
    <mark>Peugeot</mark>
    <model>206</model>
</Car>

<Truck id="truck1">
    <plate>BBB</plate>
    <mark>Scania</mark>
    <model>X1</model>
</Truck>

<Trailer id="trailer1">
    <plate>CCC</plate>
    <mark>Scania</mark>
    <model>T1</model>
</Trailer>
```

... I can now define *complex vehicle*, for example:

```
<TrailerTruck id="tt1">
    <Car refid="car1"/>
    <Trailer refid="trailer1"/>
</TrailerTruck>

<TrailerTruck id="tt2">
    <Truck refid="truck1"/>
    <Trailer refid="trailer1"/>
</TrailerTruck>
```

Okay, it works, but I noticed that - unfortunately - also allowed such a thing:

```
<TrailerTruck id="tt3_WRONG">
    <Truck refid="trailer1"/>   <!-- an element "Truck" should not
    refer to a trailer!! Should be able to refer only to truck1 -->
    <Trailer refid="car1"/>     <!-- like before, an element Trailer
    should be able to refer only trailer1 -->
</TrailerTruck>

<TrailerTruck id="tt4_WRONG">
    <Car refid="truck1"/>       <!-- an element **Car** should not
    refer to a Truck !! -->
    <Trailer refid="trailer1"/>
</TrailerTruck>
```

So, if I put incorrect references, is not shown any error. Instead, I would like to be notified. I want to insert some kind of restriction or control. But how?

---

Now I show you my current implementation.

**VehicleXMLSchema.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Fleet" type="FleetType"/>


    <xs:complexType name="FleetType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Car" />
            <xs:element ref="Truck" />
            <xs:element ref="Trailer" />
            <xs:element ref="TrailerTruck" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="VehicleType" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="plate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="mark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>




    <!-- SimpleVehicle and ComplexVehicle -->

    <xs:complexType name="SimpleVehicle">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ComplexVehicle">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType">
                <xs:attribute name="refid" type="xs:IDREF"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>




    <!-- Car, Truck, Trailer -->

    <xs:element name="Car" type="SimpleVehicle" />
    <xs:element name="Truck" type="SimpleVehicle"/>
    <xs:element name="Trailer" type="SimpleVehicle"/>




    <!-- TrailerTruck -->

    <xs:group name="DrivingPart">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Car" type="ComplexVehicle" />
            <xs:element name="Van" type="ComplexVehicle"/>
            <xs:element name="Truck" type="ComplexVehicle"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="TrailerTruck">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="DrivingPart" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="Trailer" type="ComplexVehicle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**Shipper1.xml**:

```
<Fleet shipperName="Shipper1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="VehicleXMLSchema.xsd">

    <Car id="car1">
        <plate>AAA</plate>
        <mark>Peugeot</mark>
        <model>206</model>
    </Car>

    <Truck id="truck1">
        <plate>DDD</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
        <model></model>
    </Truck>

    <Trailer id="trailer1">
        <plate>EEE</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
        <model></model>
    </Trailer>


    <TrailerTruck id="trailerTruck1">
        <Car refid="car1" />
        <Trailer refid="trailer1" />
    </TrailerTruck>

    <TrailerTruck id="trailerTruck2_WRONG">
        <Truck refid="car1" />
        <Trailer refid="trailer1" />
    </TrailerTruck>

    <TrailerTruck id="trailerTruck3_WRONG">
        <Truck refid="truck1" />
        <Trailer refid="car1" />
    </TrailerTruck>

</Fleet>
```

Comment: @sergioFC I use Eclipse IDE. I think is supported.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking for referential integrity; you really need [xsd:key/xsd:keyref](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cIdentity-constraint_Definitions). ID/IDREF are in the XSD spec for backward compatibility with DTDs; I wouldn't use them in XSDs.

This is your modified XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Fleet" type="FleetType">
        <xs:key name="PK_Cars">
            <xs:selector xpath="Car"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:key name="PK_Trucks">
            <xs:selector xpath="Truck"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:key name="PK_Trailers">
            <xs:selector xpath="Trailer"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:key name="PK_TrailerTruck">
            <xs:selector xpath="TrailerTruck"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="FK_TrailerTruck2Trailers" refer="PK_Trailers">
            <xs:selector xpath="TrailerTruck/Trailer"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@refid"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="FK_TrailerTruck2Cars" refer="PK_Cars">
            <xs:selector xpath="TrailerTruck/Car"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@refid"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="FK_TrailerTruck2Trucks" refer="PK_Trucks">
            <xs:selector xpath="TrailerTruck/Truck"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@refid"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="FleetType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Car"/>
            <xs:element ref="Truck"/>
            <xs:element ref="Trailer"/>
            <xs:element ref="TrailerTruck"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="shipperName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="VehicleType" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="plate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="mark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- SimpleVehicle and ComplexVehicle -->
    <xs:complexType name="SimpleVehicle">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ComplexVehicle">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VehicleType">
                <xs:attribute name="refid" type="xs:IDREF"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- Car, Truck, Trailer -->
    <xs:element name="Car" type="SimpleVehicle"/>
    <xs:element name="Truck" type="SimpleVehicle"/>
    <xs:element name="Trailer" type="SimpleVehicle"/>
    <!-- TrailerTruck -->
    <xs:group name="DrivingPart">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Car" type="ComplexVehicle"/>
<!--            <xs:element name="Van" type="ComplexVehicle"/>-->
            <xs:element name="Truck" type="ComplexVehicle"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:element name="TrailerTruck">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="DrivingPart" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="Trailer" type="ComplexVehicle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With the key/keyref, you now control your cross checks. The diagram below shows only content expanded to demonstrate:

- Cars and Trailers PK
- how you link trailer trucks to trailers
- how you link your driving part (a car in this case) with the associated counterpart (a car in the top section of your XML).

[image]

It is consistent with referential integrity in a "traditional" database design: you got your primary keys, foreign keys. Your posted XML will now be invalid; the one below would be the valid version of it.

```
<Fleet shipperName="Shipper1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="VehicleXMLSchema.xsd">

    <Car id="car1">
        <plate>AAA</plate>
        <mark>Peugeot</mark>
        <model>206</model>
    </Car>

    <Truck id="truck1">
        <plate>DDD</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
        <model></model>
    </Truck>

    <Trailer id="trailer1">
        <plate>EEE</plate>
        <mark>Scania</mark>
        <model></model>
    </Trailer>

    <TrailerTruck id="trailerTruck1">
        <Car refid="car1"/>
        <Trailer refid="trailer1"/>
    </TrailerTruck>

    <TrailerTruck id="trailerTruck2_WRONG">
        <Truck refid="truck1"/>
        <Trailer refid="trailer1"/>
    </TrailerTruck>

    <TrailerTruck id="trailerTruck3_WRONG">
        <Truck refid="truck1"/>
        <Trailer refid="trailer1"/>
    </TrailerTruck>

</Fleet>
```

Comment: this seems good... but isn't better create one key and refkey? Like 
 <xs:key name="PK_DrivingPart">..bla bla.. ??

Comment: With one key you would go back to the limitations of ID/IDREF; you've asked for "an element "Truck" should not refer to a trailer!! Should be able to refer only to truck1 ", etc.; therefore, you need to distinguish the IDs and their references, hence the pairs of PK/FK. I was hoping you're familiar with ER modeling, which is what key/keyref is consistent with. That being said, if you could achieve what you need with one key, then of course, do it.

Comment: Could I describe primary and foreign keys inside of their own related complex types or elements instead of collecting it in one <xs:element name="Fleet">?

Comment: @Nashev, if I got your question right, then the short answer is "No". A constraint has to be under an element, one can't use a type for it. Also, the elements referenced by the constraints must be "nested" by the element having the constraints.